# What is the word for "handwriting" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, words, word-usage, word-requests

When I looked up the word "*handwriting*" on jisho.org, it came up with:

1. 筆跡 {ひっせき}
2. 手書き {てがき}
3. 字 {じ}

So if I were to say, "*my **handwriting** is bad*," which word do I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common ways to say "my handwriting is bad" would probably be

- **字**が汚{きたな}い (汚い often means "dirty," but here's it's "bad" or "messy")
- **字**が下手{へた} (下手 means "bad" or "unskillful")

So, in that specific case **字** is the word you're looking for.

**字** refers to the actual letters themselves. You can use 字 for any letters, even ones that are printed, but based on context it will usually be clear if you mean handwriting.

**筆跡** is a broadly used term for handwritten letters or the manner of writing. It also appears in compounds like 筆跡学{ひっせきがく} (graphology) or 筆跡鑑定{ひっせきかんてい} (handwriting analysis). The fact that it is kind of a "bigger" word than 字 is what probably leads to it being used less in that kind of off-the-cuff remark.

**手書き** is writing or drawing by hand, as well as things written or drawn by hand. It's more about the process, the act of using your hand rather than a machine, than about the resulting letters themselves. Examples include 手書きでサインをする (sign by hand) or 手書きのイラスト (hand-drawn illustration).

Answer (score 4):

You would say something like 「字が汚い」, lit. my letters are dirty. Avoid saying something like 「手書きが悪い」or 「字が悪い」.